# Getting a error when creating a map of callbacks inside a class

Tags: c++, boost

The code:

```
class Base{
  enum eventTypes{ EVENT_SHOW };
  std::map<int, boost::function<bool(int,int)> > m_validate;
  virtual void buildCallbacks();
  bool shouldShowEvent(int x, int y);
};
void Base::buildCallbacks(){
   m_validate[ EVENT_SHOW ] = boost::bind(&Base::shouldShowEvent,this);
}
```

I get the following error:

```
 In base.cxx
  return (p->*f_);
  Error: a pointer to a bound function may only be used to call
      the function (boundfuncalled)
```

I get what the error is saying, I am not allowed to do anything else but call the bounded member function, but how can I circumvent that issue? I'm not sure why this shouldn't work.

Answer (score 5):

```
m_validate[ EVENT_SHOW ] = boost::bind(&Base::shouldShowEvent,this);
```

The call to `bind()` produces a function object that takes no arguments. You can't use such an object to call `Base::shouldShowEvent`, because it takes two arguments. So you have to turn the function object into one that takes two arguments:

```
m_validate[ EVENT_SHOW ] = boost::bind(&Base::shouldShowEvent,this, _1, _2);
```

(Not tested...)

Comment: This is correct, though I really wish there was a way to not worry about the arity of the member you're binding. :/

Comment: Thanks, don't know how I missed that. Been a long day.